# get id/class name on click and save txt file on server with id/class as file name

Tags: php, jquery

I already got it to work, that it writes the txt file into a folder on the server, but I have a problem with 
reading out the name of the id clicked and to write it into the file name.

At the moment when I click a button, the txt file name is just empty at the place where the id name should be.

Here's the code:

**HTML Button:**

```
 <div class="ch-item pbar11" id="start_id" onclick="capture(this);">    
 </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function capture(elem) {

var id_name = $(elem).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "savetxt.php",
            data: id_name,

        });
        return false;
}

</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$id_name = $_POST['id_name'];

$file = "saved/"."User-".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."-Zeit-".date('i-s')."-".$id_name.".txt";

$f = fopen ($file, 'a+');
fwrite($f);
fclose($f);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the value of id_name:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "savetxt.php",
        data: {id_name: id_name}

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "savetxt.php",
   data: { id_name: id_name } // pass an object, a key/value pair
});
```